# Why can the following environment module not be loaded?

Tags: environment, environment-modules

I get an error loading [environment modules (4.2.4)](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) I do not understand. With three modules A, B and C where B depends on A and C and C depends only on A:

**A**

```
#%Module1.0
```

**B**

```
#%Module1.0
module load A C
```

**C**

```
#%Module1.0
module load A
```

it is not possible to load the modules in the following manner:

```
module load A B
```

The error that is printed to stdout is:

```
Error: B cannot be loaded due to missing prereq.
  HINT: the following modules must be loaded first: C
```

A `module load A C B` is working.

Is this a bug of the module environment or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You clearly hit a bug. `module load A B` should work as you expect.

I have [reported it to the project on GitHub](https://github.com/cea-hpc/modules/issues/281)

As a work-around, you could also pass the `--auto` command-line switch:

```
$ module load --auto A B
Loading B
  Loading requirement: C
$ module list
Currently Loaded Modulefiles:
 1) A   2) C   3) B
```

Another work-around is to write `B` modulefile with 2 separate `module load` commands:

```
#%Module1.0
module load A
module load C
```

**UPDATE**: Environment Modules 4.2.5 is now released and includes a fix for this issue. So `module load A C` command in `B` modulefile correctly loads `A` and `C` modulefiles.

Comment: Thank you for reporting it. I thought that such a fundamental feature could not be buggy. I tried your work around with loading modules in separate lines and it works for me. Thank you for your help!